# is there a way to find or upper bound the largest eigenvalue of the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-theory

I have a matrix $A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ -- i.e. a matrix with 1s and 0s only.

Is there a way to find or upper bound its largest eigenvalue?

I have a feeling it is related to connectivity of directed graphs, if $A$ is thought of as adjacency matrix.

Also, when trying

```
      A = rand(10,10); A = A <= p; [x,S] = eig(A+0.00); S(1,1)
```

in Matlab for various values of p (0.1,0.2,...) (many times) it seems like S(1,1), the largest eigenvalue, is around 1/p.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may find this blog post relevant: http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/the-spectral-radius-of-a-simple-graph/

Comment: Also try [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104072/upper-bound-for-largest-eigenvalue-of-0-1-matrix)

Comment: @PatrickLi thanks, that's useful. Brad: couldn't find exactly an answer there.

Comment: You should symmetrise $A \mapsto (A+A')/2$ to get adjacency matrices...

Answer (score 4):

The largest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of a graph is bound by
$$
\delta(A)\le\mu_{\text{max}}(A)\le\Delta(A),
$$
with $\delta$/$\Delta$ being the smallest/largest vertex degree in your graph.
A proof can be found [here](http://www.math.sc.edu/~lu/teaching/2009spring_778S/adjeig.pdf) (Lemma 3). 
In your case, $\delta$/$\Delta$ lie around $\frac1p$.